# I am having issues resizing my image to fit my browser screen always

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with responsiveness in CSS. my pictures are not shrinking with increase or decrease in browser window. below is my div for the images

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="imagefolder/coding2.jpg" alt="codepic" >
    <img src="imagefolder/coding.jpg" alt="codepic">
</div>
```

also below is my style sheet class for images

```
@media  screen and (max-width:1000px){
.images {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    padding: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: auto;
    background-size: contain;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your images fit the parent by givning them a 100% width. Like this

```
.images img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
  .images {
    background-color: darkgrey;        
    padding: 25px;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
  }

  .images img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://www.inma.org/files/images/blogs/feature_photos/Oct16_Ideas-Buytaert-1800.jpg" alt="codepic"><img src="https://digitalagencynetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/what-you-can-see-from-coca-colas-digital-marketing-strategy.jpg" alt="codepic">
</div>
```

Comment: tried that and it still did not work. maybe i am missing something. i am new to css tho

Comment: in your css change the `width: 100%;` to `width: 80%;`. That will fix yur issue. This is beacusee you already have padding of 10% on both sides.

Comment: So **full width = 10% + 80% + 10%**. (full width = padding left + image width + padding right)  Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Give each image a class, `<img class="myImage" src="imagefolder/coding.jpg" alt="codepic">` and specify the width for those images: `.myImage { width: 100% //for example }`

Comment: will it work when i shrink or increase the browser window? because as of now, the images are too big for the webpage and they are not responsive

Comment: right now, you haven't been specific about the image sizes, instead you gave the parent element the width, but the images inside have the original size. By giving them a width, they will fit inside the parent container (.images). So, even without the media queries, the images will resize accordingly to the parent container

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem can be solved by either by putting each `<img>` tag inside a separate `<div>` or by doing this:

```
.imgages {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```